# Unable to use .Pdf functions to customize the data in Kendo Grid pdf export

Tags: kendo-ui, pdf-generation, kendo-grid

I am trying to export kendo grid data to PDF. It’s all working fine but it’s not allowing me to use some function of pdf method like  `RepeatHeaders` and few more. here's my code

```
.ToolBar(tools => tools.Pdf())
  .Pdf(pdf => pdf
  .AllPages()
  .Margin("2cm", "1cm", "1cm", "1cm")
  .RepeatHeaders()
  .Subject("ABC Subject")
  .FileName("ABC.pdf")
  .Title("Report: ABC")
  )
```

Here the error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'PDFSettingsBuilder' does not contain
>   a definition for 'RepeatHeaders' and no extension method
>   'RepeatHeaders' accepting a first argument of type
>   'PDFSettingsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

I'm using Kendo.Mvc version 2015.3.1111.545 (Runtime version v4.0.30319)

How would I use these functions to customize data in pdf?